# routerLink is not working in angular 2

Tags: angular, routerlink, routerlinkactive

Routing in page is not happening. I have used below HTML and config code.

```
<nav aria-label="Page navigation">
    <ul class="pagination pagination-plain">
      <li>
        <a href="review/words" aria-label="Previous">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
        <a [routerLink]="review/words">1</a>
      </li>
      <li [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
        <a [routerLink]="review/phrase">2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" aria-label="Next">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

routing config code is

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { 
    path: '', 
    component: IndexComponent,
 },
 { 
    path: 'index', 
    component: IndexComponent,
 },
 { 
    path: 'review/words', 
    component: WordsComponent,
 },
 { 
    path: 'review/phrase', 
    component: SentenceComponent,
 }
];
```

I am getting the below error when i click on '1' or '2' in my pagination link.

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes.
>   URL Segment: 'review/phrase/NaN' Error: Cannot match any routes. URL
>   Segment: 'review/phrase/NaN'
>       at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.es5.js:1404) [angular]
>       at CatchSubscriber.selector (router.es5.js:1379) [angular]
>       at CatchSubscriber.error (catch.js:104) [angular]
>       at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:128) [angular]
>       at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:102) [angular]
>       at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:128) [angular]
>       at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:102) [angular]
>       at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:128) [angular]
>       at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:102) [angular]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
<a [routerLink]="['review/words']">1</a>
```

This is how it expects input. !

Edit:
Also you dont have router container in your html.
Add this at end of template file.

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: @Partha Ghiya: Thanks for the answer. It routes to the URL. But page is not loaded until unless i refresh it. Can you please help.

Comment: @GreenComputers cause u dont have router-outlet.
Add this in your html at end. `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

Comment: @Partha Ghiya: Added. But same issue. Please help.

Comment: @GreenComputers same issue as in you had to refresh the page?? Can u create a plunkr or something

Comment: @Partha Ghiya: Shall i share my screen if you have team viewer software

Comment: You facing refresh issue ? Create some a plunkr or something. Have limited internet connectivity

Comment: My project is quit complex. It will take some time to create plunkr. Can u please check the issue in teamviewer.

Comment: Limited connectivity :(  it breaks too often. Post screenshots and error or mail me at ghiya.parth@gmail.com